# How to check checkbox when right click in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

[This is my working table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00gtd.jpg)

There are checkboxes in table. I want to check those row by row when right click on the row.

It's working with click properly. And I want when right click checked.

Please check my code:

```
<?php if (isset($sub_folders)) { ?>
     <?php foreach ($sub_folders as $sub_folder) { ?>
         <tr id="<?php echo $sub_folder['id']; ?>" class="check <?php if (($sub_folder['is_file']) == 0) { ?>folder-row<?php } ?> td_bgcolor" >
             <td><input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $sub_folder['id']; ?>" class="check_row selected_check"></td>
             <td  style="color: #c9302c"><b class="<?php if (($sub_folder['is_file']) == 0) { ?> glyphicon <?php if (($sub_folder['is_favorite']) == 1) { ?><?php echo 'glyphicon-star' ?><?php } else { ?><?php echo 'glyphicon-star-empty' ?><?php } ?><?php } ?> add-to-fav" title="Add To Favorite" id="<?php echo $sub_folder['id']; ?>"></b></td>
             <td class="<?php if (($sub_folder['is_file']) == 0) { ?> vf-icon-folder <?php } else { ?> glyphicon glyphicon-file <?php } ?>"></td>
             <td><?php if (($sub_folder['is_file']) == 0) { ?><a class="folder_click" id="<?php echo $sub_folder['id']; ?>"><?php } ?><?php echo $sub_folder['client_name']; ?></a></td>
             <td class="text-center"><?php
                                          if (isset($sub_folder['file_size'])) {
                                                                echo $sub_folder['file_size'];
                                                            }
                                                            ?></td>
                                                        <td class="text-center"><?php if ($sub_folder['updated_date'] != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') { ?><?php echo date('d-m-Y H:m:s', strtotime($sub_folder['updated_date'])); ?><?php } else { ?><?php echo '-'; ?><?php } ?></td>                                                        
                                                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $sub_folder['created_user']->first_name; ?> <?php echo $sub_folder['created_user']->last_name; ?></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
```

This is my script

```
            $('.check').bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).
                        css({
                            top: event.pageY + "px",
                            left: event.pageX + "px"
                        });
            });

            $(document).bind("mousedown", function (e) {

                if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {

                    $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
                }
            });

            $(".custom-menu li").click(function () {

                switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
                    case "copy_move":
                        alert("copy_move");
                        break;

                    case "view_details":
                        alert("view_details");
                        break;

                    case "rename":
                        alert("rename");
                        break;

                    case "delete":
                        alert("delete");
                        break;
                }
                $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
            });
```

Comment: paste your html

Comment: please write what have you tried so far.

Comment: Look at this [link](https://api.jquery.com/contextmenu/)

Comment: `$('tr').on('contextmenu', function() {
    console.log(this.id)
});` Use something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `contextmenu()` method for right click on tr.

```
$('tr.check').contextmenu(function(e){
   $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"].check_row').prop('checked',true);
   return false; // not display default menu.
});
```